# Trying to get streamlive.to rtmp stream to work

Tags: rtmp

How do I get the token?

Their source website says something like this:

```js
var token="";
$.getJSON("http://www.streamlive.to/server.php?id=1431994763", function(json) {
    token = json.token;
    setStream(token);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the token is stored in your variable,named "token"
It was declared when it was defined as the JSON object also named "token", which was established from the getJSON function

you can find your token in the console by typing in the following
console.log(token)

// Do understand that this token expires.. Maybe every 15 min? hour? day? week? month? You should find this out so that you may know how long before you have to get a new token or if you can find a way to redeem/renew the token.